# Checkout Correct Tag in Git

Tags: git

I have a git repository of the stable kernel builds
my remote 'origin' is as follows

```
origin  git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git (fetch)
origin  git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git (push)
```

Now as per kernelnewbies.org i have to use the following command to get a snapshot of a particular kernel version

```
git checkout -b stable tag
```

I did this

```
git checkout -b v2.6.34.12
```

but when i check the kernel version using

```
make kernelversion
```

I get the latest version that is 3.11.6.

Is the git command correct or am i missing something?

Comment: For next time: if `stable tag` was a single argument, it would have been written `<stable tag>`.

Comment: Sorry. My bad... i just copied it from kernel Newbies... i should correct it i think

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that this:

```
git checkout -b v2.6.34.12
```

creates a new branch called `v2.6.34.12` that is located at whatever you happen to have checked out at the moment - `v2.6.34.12` is the argument to the `-b` option, and names the branch that you want to create.

Instead, you want this:

```
git checkout -b mybranch v2.6.34.12
```

to create a new branch (called, imaginitively, `mybranch`), and start it at the `v2.6.34.12` tag (but be careful, at this point, as you've already created a branch with the name `v2.6.34.12` that you should probably delete first as `git rev-parse` will likely find the branch before it finds the tag - you could specify the last argument above as `refs/tags/v2.6.34.12` to explicitly request the tag instead of a similarly named branch).

Answer (score 1):

```
usage: git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
```

just add `<start point>`

```
git checkout -b formake v2.6.34.12
```

your

```
git checkout -b v2.6.34.12
```

equals

```
git checkout -b v2.6.34.12 HEAD
```

it creates a new branch named v2.6.34.12 from master

Comment: what is formake ? would you please explain a little on that

Comment: Actually, `git checkout -b v2.6.34.12` == `git checkout -b v2.6.34.12 HEAD` - makes a very big difference if you weren't on `master` to begin with...

Comment: @ArunKumar `formake` is the branch name, since tag cant be modified. just copy `v2.6.34.12 ` to a branch and switch to it. your working copy is now same as `v2.6.34.12 `, you can make now